# Apache shows index of/ instead of default index html

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I installed apache2 on my Ubuntu 13.10 and it works without any problems. I can see the default index page (which is located in /var/www/index.html) by typing localhost/ in the address bar

[image: Apache default page]

Today, after I upgraded my Ubuntu to 14. 04 the localhost server doesn't work any longer and shows index of/ page instead

[image: Apache index listing]

I have tried to reinstall everything (including `php5`, `phpMyAdmin`, and `MySQL`) but the problem is still there. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should edit the `000-default.conf` file

To edit `000-default.conf` you can open it in a text editor with root permission, for example:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

By default `DocumentRoot` is as below:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

You need to change the `DocumentRoot` to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
```

Save the file and exit.

After this you must restart your Apache server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```