# Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Server Apache 2 - replacing index.html shows index of/ instead?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

Good day, I've set up my server online over DigitalOcean, I followed their guides on how to set up an Ubuntu 14.04.x x64 server, setting up a LAMP stack, and installing phpMyAdmin. Everything is working fine, the `mySite.com` shows the apache setup page. However, when I uploaded my new index.html (located at `/var/www/html/index.html` file (I renamed the default one to index-default.html) and then refreshed my site, instead of showing my site, it shows `Index Of/`. I tried `mySite.com/index.html` and it works. It's just a bit of a hassle to have the user type in `mySite.com/index.html` and I know it can work with just `mySite.com`. I opened up FileZilla to check if this may be caused by the difference of the permissions and ownership, and they were initially different. I updated the permissions and ownership and now they have the same sets:

[image: Index Files]

where `index-default.html` was the default apache index page and `index.html` is my new one.

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450211/apache-shows-index-of-instead-of-default-index-html) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740976/im-getting-this-you-should-replace-this-file-located-at-var-www-html-index-h), however, these mainly point to redirecting the default directory to `/var/www` instead of `/var/www/html` and I'm sitting quite comfortably over at my `/var/www/html` and would like to work from there.

I feel like I'm overlooking something relatively simple. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I ran `sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`

And then I saw that it didn't say `index.html`. It had `index.php` twice.

It now reads

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```